# Mongo client {Mongo-Java-driver} creation hangs duration . No exception thrown

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I have a cron-job running at a Linux machine running after every 5 minutes. The job executes a Java class.

```
    private MongoClient createConnection(int retry,List<ServerAddress> host){  
    try {  
        System.out.println("Retrying----------"+retry);  

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(host, MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .connectionsPerHost(10)
                .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(5)
                .connectTimeout(5000).writeConcern(WriteConcern.NORMAL).build());
        client.getDB("admin").command("ping").throwOnError();  
        retry = 0;  
        return client;  
    }  catch (Exception e) {  
        retry++;  
        if (retry < retryLimit) {  
            createConnection(retry,host);  
        } else {  
            System.out.println("Connection could not be established to host-"+host);  
        }  
        return null;
    }
}
```

retry is the integer value denoting how many times client creation can be tried in case host is unreachable.

The host list that i am passing is -

```
        public static List<ServerAddress> HOST_SCRIPT = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    {
        try {
            add(new ServerAddress("PrimaryHost23", 27017));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Code is Stuck when i MongoClient is being created. It does not happen always. Code works fine and NEVER hangs when i run on my local machine. There is no exception thrown.
I recently upgraded Linux machine OS (from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6). Can this be responsible for this because this script was working fine earlier.
Please help.

Regards,
Vibhav

Answer (score -1):

The thing what you can do is you can throw mongo exception try out that of mongo client is stuck you will get to know try out this https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/MongoException.html

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more.
How i can know whether it is stuck or not while creating mongoClient?

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course, actually i was creating crawler in java which fetch all the links of any particular website  and validate the css and html structure Using the Jsoup and jcabi api but when i used to store links to the database it was not throwing any exception and even not storing the data also. so i did this

```
 catch (MongoException e){
        System.err.print(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: As you can see my code is already in try catch block.
If MongoException is thrown, that will be caught by adjacent catch block. my Code stucks on the line where MongoClient is being prepared.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the compatibility like of jar that you have uploaded for your project like before it was like Mongo mongo = new Mongo(host,port); but That is deprecated. Try to check that and even your MongoDb jar.